# Acquiring host address from manual WiFi Direct connection

Tags: android, networking, wifi, host

I have connected 2 devices via WiFi Direct. This is done manually, and therefore no code has been written for this. In order to send data between the devices, I need the "client" to be able to acquire the host address for the "server".

Is this possible? And if so, any tips on how to go about it?

*PS: I know very little of networking, so please excuse any faulty logic.*

Answer (score 0):

This is possible for sure. Even you can setup and automate wifi-direct connection via code.

here is nice repo you can refer. https://github.com/mayfourth/WiFi-Direct-File-Transfer

Comment: Yes, I have looked at code such as that before. What I wish to do is find the IP address of any device which is connected via WiFi direct. I wish to skip the setup in code, and therefore skip discovering peers, as I will already be connected, and this seems to be where the IP address is usually gathered.

Comment: You can broadcast your query over network to broadcast IP address probably (255.255.255.255) and ask other peer to reply back with their ips information. Note that i never tried this approach over wifi-direct, but it works over classical Wifi. Logically it should work